# B tree class implementation: expression must have constant values?

Tags: c++, b-tree, constant-expression

Suppose that we have a "itemtype.h" header file, where I declare the following items:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

const int  keyfieldmax=12;
const int kfmaxplus=keyfieldmax+1;
const int datafieldmax=36;
const int dfmaxplus=datafieldmax+1;
const int NULLCHAR='\0';
typedef char keyfieldtype[kfmaxplus];
typedef char datafieldtype[dfmaxplus];
typedef struct
{
    keyfieldtype  keyfield;
    datafieldtype datafield;
}itemType;
```

Now, from this header I need to create "btree.h"

```
#include "table.h"
int maxkeys=11;
int maxkeysplus=maxkeys+1;
const int minkeys=5;
const int nilptr=-1L;
typedef struct
{
    int count;
    itemType Key[maxkeys];
    long branch[maxkeysplus];
}NodeType
```

but with the following two lines

```
itemType Key[maxkeys];
long branch[maxkeysplus];
```

it says that expression must have constant values. So how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Make maxkeys and maxkeysplus a const int

```
const int maxkeys = 11;
const int maxkeysplus = maxkeys + 1;
```

Comment: @dato check again. You might have missed a `const`.

Comment: @dato: Do a full rebuild to be sure.  It should not have the exact same error if you made those lines `const`.